# SYMFONY NELMIO CORS issue : Access-Control-Allow-Origin header contains multiple values

Tags: php, symfony, nelmiocorsbundle

I created an API with symfony, FOSRestBundle and NelmioCorsBundle and I connect to it with a Ionic APP. some routes return me a CORS error :

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://dev.myapp.com/api/login_check' fromfrom localhost/:1 origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to the preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost/8100, *', but only one is allowed.

there is some part of my code :

config/nelmio_cors.yml :

```
nelmio_cors:
   defaults:
       allow_credentials: false
       allow_origin: []
       allow_headers: []
       allow_methods: []
       expose_headers: []
       max_age: 0
       hosts: []
       origin_regex: false
   paths:
       '^/api':
           allow_origin: ['*']
           allow_headers: ['*']
           allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
           max_age: 3600
```

I tried to add this in the .htaccess but without success:

```
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
```

Someone have an idea about this problem ? thanks you

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working example:

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        allow_origin: []
        allow_headers: []
        allow_methods: []
        expose_headers: []
        max_age: 0
        hosts: []
        origin_regex: false
        forced_allow_origin_value: ~
    paths:
        '^/api/':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
            allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600
        '^/':
            origin_regex: true
            allow_origin: ['%env(string:CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
            allow_headers: ['X-Custom-Auth']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600
            hosts: [ '^api\.' ]
```

Also your in your .env or .env.local :

```
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN='^https?://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)(:[0-9]+)?$'
```

Comment: hello, I tried with your example but the issue still persist